# Changing VMware OpenGL version

Tags: vmware, opengl

I'm running Windows XP on VMware, and the graphics adapter has support for OpenGL 2. I need to test some stuff in an enviroment with OpenGL 1.4. When I disable "Accelerate 3d graphics" I get a system with OpenGL 1.1, which doesn't work for me. How can I downgrade VMware's graphics adapter to use OpenGL 1.4?